# How to add a goto to a for loop

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a script that edits files and I am building a choice goto menu.

The script itself works fine, it reads from a file name that has ( ) in it. So my files are saved like this `(1) filename.txt, (2) filename.txt ....(100) filename.txt` 
the content of the file has `"times": 125489,` saved in it, the script removes the 100 from the file name and does this `"times": 100,`

This is a small part of my content for my txt files it has a 4 indent space per line I believe the format is Json

```
  "aidr": 3.58,
  "nlpr": 0.5,
  "tafr": 0.5,
  "titp": 0.5,
  "trld": 0.0,
  "tssp": 0.5,
  "tssr": 0.5,
  "ttup": 0.5,
  "ttpp": 0.5,
  "times": 125,
  "Stamp": 125,
  "ppiid": 649,
  "otiid": 649,
  "apcid": 9,
  "orcid": 9,
  "jpcns": 0,
  "agpns": 0,
  "opcns": 0,
  "rppns": 0,
```

I recently found that when I merged all my single scripts together it slows down dramatically. Before the script processed 500 .txt files in 1 minute but now it takes 30 minutes.

My goal is to find a way to bring back the speed of this script.

I heard and read that adding a goto before and after the loop could make the script fast again.

```
@echo off

:Menu
ECHO ################################################################ 
echo.
ECHO                   1 - Script 1
ECHO                   2 - Script 2
ECHO                   3 - Script 3
ECHO                   4 - Script 4
ECHO                   5 - Script 5
ECHO                   100 - Script 100
echo.
set pass=
:: the choice command
set /p Mchoice=Make Your Choice: 
::goto choices
goto=:%Mchoice%
goto %goto%

:1
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "ToReplace1="times": "

SET "sourcedir=New folder 1"
SET "destdir=New fodler 2"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
(
  FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%q") DO (
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%sourcedir%\%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:times=!" CALL :Nums1 %%j
   echo(!line!
  )
 )

)>"%destdir%\%%q"

)
GOTO :Menu

:Nums1
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%ToReplace1%%%s=%ToReplace1%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto Nums1
set "line=!line:%ToReplace1%=%ToReplace1%%1!"
GOTO :eof

:2
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "ToReplace2="Stamp": "

SET "sourcedir=New folder 1"
SET "destdir=New fodler 2"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
(
  FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%q") DO (
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%sourcedir%\%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:Stamp=!" CALL :Nums2 %%j
   echo(!line!
  )
 )

)>"%destdir%\%%q"

)
GOTO :Menu

:Nums2
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%ToReplace2%%%s=%ToReplace2%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto Nums1
set "line=!line:%ToReplace2%=%ToReplace2%%1!"
GOTO :eof

:15
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd /d "%~dp0"

set "ToReplace1="times": "
set "ToReplace2="Stamp": "
set "ToReplace3="jpcns": "

SET "sourcedir15=New folder 1"
SET "destdir15=New fodler 2"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir15%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
 SET "newdest=%%~dpq"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:%sourcedir15%=%destdir15%!"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:~0,-1!"
 MD "!newdest!" 2>nul

(
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%~nxq") DO (
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:times=!" CALL :Nums15 %%j
   if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:Stamp=!" CALL :Nums15 %%j
   if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:jpcns=!" CALL :Nums15 %%j
   echo(!line!
  )
 )
)>"!newdest!\%%~nxq" 

)
GOTO :Menu

:Nums15
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%ToReplace1%%%s=%ToReplace1%!"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%ToReplace2%%%s=%ToReplace2%!"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%ToReplace3%%%s=%ToReplace3%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto Nums15
set "line=!line:%ToReplace1%=%ToReplace1%%1!"
set "line=!line:%ToReplace2%=%ToReplace2%%1!"
set "line=!line:%ToReplace3%=%ToReplace3%%1!"
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: Likely the cause of the lethargy is repeatedly executing `findstr`, but there appears to be no connection between your posted code and the `choice goto menu`. Perhaps if you reveal quite what you expect your code to do, with sample data and expected result it may become clearer. The `edit` button allows you to add the new data into the question.

Comment: The script on it's own run real fast, but once I decided to put my work together into 1 batch script it slowed down, like it would complete the task at hand in 30 minutes with normal it can do the same job in 1 minute, I believe the reason is because the new batch script is like 200K lines long and it has to loop through the whole script to come back to it, I could be wrong, but I read that if we can add a goto before and after the Loop this will make it fast again

Comment: I have bee reading on this site to gather ideas, but not sure how to intergrade this to my script `https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3487`

Comment: Oh boy... sample data ..um going to try the best way to add more the the ask

Comment: @Magoo - OK, I think I got what you asked

Comment: @JRSantos You're welcome! And, welcome to SO! Can you add one or two really short sample files showing the important file content?

Comment: I would also advise, along with your sample file content, that you tell us what type of encoding they use, _(ANSI with codepage; or Unicode with UTF type, and with or without BOM)_, and their line ending style, _(CR, LF, or CRLF)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a few exercises on this problem, but I've been unable to locate anything that might result in a 30:1 speed difference.

This version

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%q") DO (
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /N "^" "%sourcedir%\%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%c"
   if defined line (
    IF "%%c" equ "!line:times=!" (ECHO %%c) ELSE (
     for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%v in ("%%c") do ECHO %%v: %%j,
    )
   ) ELSE ECHO(
  )
 )
)>"%destdir%\%%q"
)
```

Seemed to be a little faster.

This:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%q") DO (
  SET "skipover="
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%sourcedir%\%%q"') do (
   IF DEFINED skipover (ECHO(%%b
   ) ELSE (
    set "line=%%b"
    if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:times=!" SET "skipover=y"&CALL :Nums1 %%j
    echo(!line!
   )
  )
 )
)>"%destdir%\%%q"
)
```

uses a Boolean variable `skipover` to bypass some of the processing once the target line has been found and manipulated - but it actually seemed slower.

This

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%q") DO (
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /N "^" "%sourcedir%\%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%c"
   if defined line (
    IF "%%c" equ "!line:times=!" (ECHO %%c) ELSE (
     for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%v in ("%%c") do ECHO %%v: %%j,
    )
   ) ELSE ECHO(
  )
 )
)>"%destdir%\%%q"
)
```

was consistently a little faster than the original - it avoids the subroutine call.

And this:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%q") DO (
  SET "skipover="
  for /F "usebackqdelims=" %%e in ("%sourcedir%\%%q") do (
   IF DEFINED skipover (ECHO/%%e
   ) ELSE (
    set "line=%%e"
    if defined line (
     IF "%%e" equ "!line:times=!" (ECHO %%e
     ) ELSE (
      SET "skipover=Y"
      for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%v in ("%%e") do ECHO %%v: %%j,
     )
    ) ELSE ECHO/
   )
  )
 )
)>"%destdir%\%%q"
)
```

was consistently nearly twice as fast, using the skip-if-it's been-changed technique and avoiding `findstr`. It won't reproduce empty lines, though.

I also found that the position of the target in the source was signiificant. Using a 700-line version of the sample data, placing the target at the end was half-speed of placing it at the start of the file, so I was able to get nearly a 4:1 speed difference between the original and this last technique if the target was placed early in the source data (running 1,000 700-line files).

I presume that `sub` appeared in the original post by way of editing-out the irrelevant portions of the code, but it seemed to be reversed in sense, the way it was written...

--- based on version 3,

```
:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="


:: Read controls from file "%1"

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*" %%b IN ("%~1") DO (
 SET "#%%b=%%c"
 FINDSTR /x /i /L /c:":#%%b" <"%~f0" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO LABEL ":#%%b" NOT found&SET "destdir="
)

IF NOT DEFINED destdir ECHO Required LABEL(s) NOT found &GOTO :eof

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
(
 rem %%q contains the name of the file to be processed
 rem remove variables starting $
 FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="
 rem extract filenumber if sourcefilename is (number)something
 SET "filenumber="
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%q") DO SET "filenumber=%%j"
 rem
 rem now process the file
 for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /N "^" "%sourcedir%\%%q"') do (
  set "line=%%c"
  if defined line (
   rem if any #name is detected, take action
   SET "processline=Y"
   FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=#=" %%u IN ('set #') DO IF DEFINED processline IF "%%c" neq "!line:%%u=!" (
    SET "processline="
    CALL :#%%u %%v 
   )
   IF DEFINED processline ECHO %%c
  ) ELSE ECHO/
 )
)>"%destdir%\%%q"
)

GOTO :eof

:#times
rem replace times value with filenumber
ECHO     "times": %filenumber%,
GOTO :eof

:#titp
rem replace titp value with value read from file (%1)
ECHO     "titp": %1,
GOTO :eof

:#tssp
rem put newz value before and zwen value after tssp value
ECHO     "newz": whatever,
ECHO %line%
ECHO     "zwen": revetahw,
GOTO :eof

:#trld
rem delete all trld values
GOTO :eof

:#tssr
rem replace the third and the fifth tssr value (I have multiples)
rem note that all $ variables are deleted FOR each file
SET /a $#tssr+=1
IF %$#tssr%==3 ECHO     "tssr": thirdtime,&GOTO :eof
IF %$#tssr%==5 ECHO     "tssr": fifthtime,&GOTO :eof
ECHO %line%

GOTO :eof
```

Using a control file contents

```
times #
titp jello
trld #
tssp #
tssr #
```

So - this is an attempt to obviate the repeated cloning of the file-processing logic.

First, I'm setting all variables that start `#` to *nothing*, un-defining them. That way, the remainder of the code knows that any variable starting `#` has not been inherited from elsewhere.

Next step : read the file to set up
#times=#
#titp=jello
#trld=#
#tssp=#
#tssr=#

The code then examines itself to make sure that subroutines `:#times` etc all exist and complains if they don't. `destdir` is simply a convenient non-empty variable used as a flag - we'll abort if the subroutines are missing, so no problem there.

Next - read the filenames. Obviously, the filemask may change depending on the selection made from the menu.

Then, for each file, kill all `$` variables for the same reason as `#` but this time for each file to be processed.

Then set up variables to contain whatever data about the file is appropriate. Could be size, date, whatever - extract-parenethesised-number is shown. No harm in doing such things for all files, even if the data is not used for this particular menu selection.

Then process the file, detecting the keystrings from the `#` array. Call `:#keystring` if found, regurgitate line if not.

Each `:#` routine does what it does. A variety of possibilities is shown. Naturally, any particular routine could be controlled further by testing the selection made.

Setting the value assigned to `#?` to a value other than `#` will deliver that value to the `:#?` subroutine as parameters. Use them as you will - constants, whatever - just interpret the parameters delivered.

Naturally, you could set the `#` variables manually for particular menu selections instead of reading them from a file.

But - this is drifting way away from the timing problem - just adding more facilities (I'm a chronic implementor of bells and whistles) so I'd suggest to end discussion here.

Comment: Hello and Thank you for the help - I am trying to apply a double or triple code editing to the updated script - but nothing I do works - Normally I would double this `if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:times=!" CALL :Nums1 %%j` - but when I try with yours it nothing gets edited

Comment: I tried to double this but fails to edit the files - `IF "%%c" equ "!line:times=!" (ECHO %%c) ELSE (` trying to put `time` and `stamp` in the same script

Comment: So you are attempting to change `stamp` as well as `times` - are there any other elements to change - and what is the new value of `stamp` and those other elements?

Comment: yes, I have several versions of my script, that all do the same type of job and I also have a version of my script for Sub reading folders,  I have `txt` files that only require 1 code editing, and I have some that require 2, 3, 6 codes editing, So script 1 will edit time and Stamp and both read `(file number)` version 2 will not read the `file number`, but I have already figured that part out, I would edit this section for other editing `%%v: %%j,` like this  `%%v: 500,`  so any code I list will get 500 added. I did this for testing ` `%%v: Test%%j,` and I got `time: Test1,`

Comment: I didn't want to over whelm anyone here with all my versions, I figured I could use this updated script to update my other scripts since they are all the same in a way. If you like I would be more then happy to share one of my other scripts so you can see what I do, if I'm allowed to do that

Comment: So far I have updated my Sub Reader Script with your version 3, I got everything working great - now I'm working on making it edit 2 or more codes at the same time

Comment: lol...I'm getting close, so far it double the content in my txt files and but both edits did appear

Comment: I have added menu `:15` so you can see how I set it up for multiple edits - I was able to add your Version 3 to it on my tester and it does work, but I still can't figure out the multi-edits

Comment: Holy cow that is very long...lol - thank you very much